# Streaming Youtube audio with GO

Tags: go, audio-streaming, youtube-dl

I am trying to use youtube-dl to get the audio URL of a youtube video, send a GET request towards that URL and then use the requests body `io.ReadCloser` and pass that to https://github.com/faiface/beep decoder.

So when I do this with different encodings I get the following error:

`mp3: MPEG version 2.5 is not supported`
or
`mp3: only layer3 (want 1; got 2) is supported`

`wav: missing RIFF at the beginning >`

`flac: flac.parseStreamInfo: invalid FLAC signature; expected "fLaC", got "\x00\x00\x00\x18"`

as you can see my knowledge of audio encoding is pretty much non existent. Since these errors dont tell me much.

But from what I have gathered is that its probably mp3 that is the desired format. And that MPEG 2.5 is some kind of proprietary format? And what I probably want is MPEG version 2 or 1? Is that possible with youtube-dl?

Also is there some other way of doing this instead (streaming audio from youtube with GO?)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"

    "github.com/faiface/beep"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/mp3"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/speaker"
)

func main() {
    audioUrl, err := GetAudioLink(
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
        "mp3",
        "140",
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req, err := http.Get(audioUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f := req.Body

    streamer, format, err := mp3.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    speaker.Init(format.SampleRate, format.SampleRate.N(time.Second/60))
    done := make(chan bool)
    speaker.Play(beep.Seq(streamer, beep.Callback(func() {
        done <- true
    })))

    <-done
}

func GetAudioLink(url, format, youtubedlQuality string) (audioUrl string, err error) {
    var cmd []byte
    if cmd, err = exec.Command(
        "youtube-dl",
        "--extract-audio",
        "--get-url",
        "--audio-format",
        format,
        "-f",
        youtubedlQuality,
        url,
    ).Output(); err != nil {
        return audioUrl, fmt.Errorf("calling youtube-dl: %w", err)
    }
    audioUrl = strings.TrimSpace(string(cmd))
    return audioUrl, err
}
```

Make sure that you are using the master branch of https://github.com/faiface/beep `go get github.com/faiface/beep@master`

And you need a local installation of youtube-dl. I couldnt find any GO lib for this.